# Cannot run Pyomo with Gurobi under Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, pyomo, gurobi

I am running an optimization model in colab using Gurobi. But, I got a warning and error message "ApplicationError":

```
opt = SolverFactory("gurobi")
```

WARNING: Could not locate the 'gurobi' executable, which is required for
solver gurobi
ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'gurobi'

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Gurobi at the start of your Colab session via this command:

```
%pip install gurobipy
```